# HLS NGINX-RTMP [error] 1281#0: *58 hls: force fragment split: 10.002 sec

Tags: nginx, rtmp, http-live-streaming

If you could shed some light for me i would appreciate it.

So, basically i am pulling a stream from my encoder and it works, i get the m3u8 output and it is accesible but the HLS video is jumpy and i lose frames. the play is not continuous.

```
2017/06/12 16:04:09 [error] 1281#0: *58 hls: force fragment split: 10.002 sec
```

(Edit after pulling from RTSP...)
2017/06/13 10:48:55 [error] 1281#0: *763 hls: force fragment split: 10.416 sec, , client: XX, server: 0.0.0.0:1935

Here is my config file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application live {
        live on;

        exec_pull ffmpeg -re -i rtsp://xxx/xxx -c copy -f flv rtmp://xxx:1935/live/xxx;

        exec_pull ffmpeg -re -i rtsp://xxx:8080/xxx -c copy -f flv rtmp://xxx:1935/live/xxx;

        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /tmp/hls/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;

        }
    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

         # rtmp statistics
        location /stat {
        rtmp_stat all;
        rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }

    location /stat.xsl {
        # you can move stat.xsl to a different location
        # under linux you could use /var/user/www for example
        root html;          
    }

    location / {
        # Disable cache
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        types {
            application/dash+xml mpd;
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

                root /tmp/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `pull` is for RTMP streams if the [documentation](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#pull) is up-to-date. Are you using a RTMPT stream as input?

Comment: I edited the post, changed the source i am pulling to rtsp and added the stat image to illustrate better. If you could help me out it would be appreciated. Also thought about setting a local computer and replicate the same configuration to see if the problem is with my hosting provider. I have a dedicated server for this.

Comment: Try the `ffmpeg` commands in CLI first to see if there are any reported errors for those sources. About the message error, you're copying the source encoding meaning you use the existing keyframes which may not be exactly 3s apart.

Comment: no errors in CLI, like i did it with a local file, a movie and it went fine. I even considered the fact that my encoders are in south america and the server is a godaddy dedicated server in the us... , should i lower the frame to 1 or increase it? I will try tweaking that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OK So.. i have news. Basically that configuration was perfect. The reason why i was losing all these packages was because of the distance between the encoder and the dedicated server.

Advised to have the server locally where the encoders are... So, that for me worked.

Cheers**

Comment: For  real? not any other  reason?